# How return NaN if not found indice in multiindex series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multi-index

I have two DataFrames df1 and df2 with many columns

df1 - [2756003 rows x 44 columns]

df2 - [22035 rows x 11 columns]

i need add new column to df2 with mean of target column from df1
based on group by result (for same columns in df1 and df2)

```
t1 = df1.groupby(['category', 'manufacturer'])
t2=t1[c1].mean()
str1='_'.join(col)
df2[c1+'_'+str1+'_mean']=t2[df2[['category','manufacturer']].as_matrix()].values
```

which return:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

t2 - store multiindex series like:

```
category  manufacturer
1         2                0.000000
          4                8.796840
          10               2.312407
          19               1.135094
          24               4.355000
```

If i use existing index i'll get expected result

```
In [302]: t2[1, 2]
Out[302]: 0.0
```

But if i call t2[410, 332], where 332 it's id of manufacturer which presented in df2 and not presented in df1, i'll get

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I want get NaN instead like we get from

```
df2['manufacturer'].map(t2)
```

in case there only one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.merge` to merge `df2` and `t2`:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2, t2.reset_index(), on=['category','manufacturer'], how='left')
```

Since, by default, `pd.merge` joins on all shared columns, if `'category'` and `'manufacturer'` are the only
columns `df2` and `t2.reset_index()` share in common, then the line above can be simplied to

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2, t2.reset_index(), how='left')
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(100,3)), columns=['category', 'manufacturer', 'col'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(100,3)), columns=['category', 'manufacturer', 'col2'])

t1 = df1.groupby(['category', 'manufacturer'])
c1 = 'col'
t2 = t1[c1].mean()
col = ['foo', 'bar']
str1='_'.join(col)
t2.name = c1+'_'+str1+'_mean'
df2 = pd.merge(df2, t2.reset_index(), on=['category','manufacturer'], how='left')
print(df2.head())
```

prints

```
   category  manufacturer  col2  col_foo_bar_mean
0         1             1     2          1.333333
1         3             4     3               NaN
2         4             4     2               NaN
3         3             3     1          1.000000
4         3             2     1          1.777778
```

Since this is a "left-join", rows in `df2` for which there is no corresponding
row in `t2` are assigned `NaN` for columns with missing values.

Comment: There was  

`AttributeError: 'CategoricalIndex' object has no attribute 'is_dtype_equal'`

after  

`df2 = pd.merge(df2, t2.to_frame(), left_on=['category','manufacturer'], 
               right_index=True, how='left')`

so i modify this part to  

`df2 = pd.merge(df2, t2.reset_index(), left_on=['category','manufacturer'], right_on=['category','manufacturer'], how='left')`

And it's worked! Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks for the correction. Since `left_on` and `right_on` specify the same column names, you can simply it to `on=['category','manufacturer']`. And if these are the only columns shared by the 2 DataFrames, you can even omit it entirely.